# Update github webpage directly from webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, github

This may sound a confusing question, but I'll try my best to explain it.

Essentially I have a github webpage, and in my webpage, if I click a button, it dynamically adds some text to the page, like a line of html.

Then when I refresh, its gone, as expected.

**What I would like**

After I add the line of html dynamically through JQ append, then I want to directly **push to github** from there, and so my website online gets updated that way.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean a github pages webpage with a repo hosted on github? ( https://pages.github.com/ )

Comment: yes its a `<name>.github.io`

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible, and if so how?

You can use CRUD methods via [Github's V3 API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file), specifically the [Update File PUT method](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file)

However, exposing Github API access tokens on the client is usually a Bad Idea™

Comment: You can perform HTTP requests via a browser as well using AJAX

Answer (score 0):

If the page is hosted on github pages, I believe you can do it using Github API:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file

For a detailed overview see:

https://mdswanson.com/blog/2011/07/23/digging-around-the-github-api-take-2.html

Comment: This requires to do it through a terminal does it not? I want just webpage?

Comment: No, actually it does not require terminal at all - it's just API calls using simple javascript and AJAX. jQuery or any other library of choice should simplify the process a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you build an API that makes the appropriate git commands running on the server. That's a bit unusual though. It might be better to store dynamic content into a database and have it fetched to build the page.